# UICollectionView multiple Selection Reusability issue

Tags: ios, uicollectionview

I am new to `UICollectionview.` I have made a simple sample were I can apply multiple selection of image. but I'am getting issue regarding selection, the issue is when I scroll collection view the check mark are added to other cells and the images array count is different at `didSelectedItem` and `didDeselectItem`.

Here is the sample code which i have tried [Sample Link](https://www.copy.com/s/Mid1STP9UQgbja2Y)

Comment: There is logical flow error in your code. Fix it!

Comment: What is Local flow error..!

Answer (score 0):

When you scroll in a `CollectionView` (or a in `TableView` for that matter), the cells are reused. 
To keep the selection while scrolling you need to keep an array of the selected `IndexPaths` and update the cells accordingly in your `collectionView:cellForItemAtIndexPath:`. That means removing the checkmark or setting it if the selected array contains this `IndexPath`.