# Selection and unselection isselection issue in UICollectionView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, uiimageview, uicollectionviewcell

I am facing the same issue [Multiple selections Issue](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26420356/3378413)

Here is my code which I have done.

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    RCCollectionCell* cell = [_channelCollectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"RC" forIndexPath: indexPath];
    cell.layer.cornerRadius = 5.0f;
    cell.layer.borderWidth=1.0f;
    cell.layer.borderColor=[UIColor lightGrayColor].CGColor;
    if (indexPath.row < [_fC count]){
        [cell setChannel:_favoriteChannels[indexPath.row]];
        [_channelCollectionView selectItemAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:NO scrollPosition:UICollectionViewScrollPositionNone];
    } else {
        //NSLog(@"Error cell %d requested only %d channels in incident", (int)indexPath.row, (int)[_incident.channels count]);
    }
    return cell;
}  
- (UICollectionReusableView *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind:(NSString *)kind atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    RCCollectionCell* cell = [_channelCollectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"RC" forIndexPath: indexPath];
    return cell;
}
- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    RCCollectionCell* cell = (RCCollectionCell*)[collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    Channel* channel = [self getChannelForIndexPath:indexPath];
    if ([_upload.channels containsObject:channel.uuid]) {
        [_upload.channels removeObject:channel.uuid];
        cell.selectedImage.hidden = YES;

    } else {
        [self.view makeToast:channel.name duration:1.5 position:CSToastPositionCenter];

        [_upload.channels addObject:channel.uuid];
        cell.selectedImage.hidden = NO;
    }
    [collectionView deselectItemAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
}
```

My Problem is `cell.selectedImage.hidden = NO;` when I click on any cell and when I scroll the collectionview I can see that another cell is also affected with selectedimage.hidden = no.

Please suggest me some solutions to resolve this issue.

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:**

`selectedImage` is a checkmark image which I am using to check and uncheck the cell.

Comment: In `if` part you need to write `cell.selectedImage.hidden = YES;`

Comment: What's the goal of using UICollectionView selection? I don't see any logic that depends on selected items

Comment: @dahiya_boy I can't understand. can you please elaborate?

Comment: @TiranUt I am using collection view to show horizontal list view which includes image text and a checkmark image.

Comment: what to write in if condition?

Comment: .Please see my updated question

Comment: You need to handle **cell.selectedImage.hidden = NO; or cell.selectedImage.hidden = YES** inside the **cellForItemAtIndexPath** method.

Comment: How? I don't understand.

Comment: I don't get why you call `selectItemAtIndexPath:indexPath` inside `cellForItemAtIndexPath`, `didSelectItemAtIndexPath` is not called when you select cell manually with `selectItemAtIndexPath`. So you have to update selectedImage.hidden in two places: inside `cellForItemAtIndexPath` and on select event inside `didSelectItemAtIndexPath`. And since you're actually not using multiple selection and handling selection manually, you can get rid of it. Simple single selection would be enough

Comment: No, I am using multiple selections.

Comment: All the appearance of UICollectionViewCell is codded in **cellForItemAtIndexPath**. On scrolling the collection view this method will invoke. So if you want to change cell appearance, do that changes in the **cellForItemAtIndexPath** method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you create a NSMutableArray to store the selected collectionview indexpaths.

```
NSMutableArray *SelectedIndexes = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
```

and add the indexpath in the **if conditoin of didselect** method

```
[SelectedIndexes addObject:indexPath];
```

And remove the **indexpath inside "else" condition of didselect method.**

```
if ([SelectedIndexes containsObject:indexPath]) {
    [SelectedIndexes removeObject:indexPath];
}
```

In your **cellForItemAtIndexPath** method check for the selected indexpath.

```
if ([SelectedIndexes containsObject:indexPath]) {
   cell.selectedImage.hidden = YES;
}
else {
    cell.selectedImage.hidden = NO;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, man It's working! I have done slightly change in if ([SelectedIndexes containsObject:indexPath]) {
   cell.selectedImage.hidden = YES;
}
else {
    cell.selectedImage.hidden = NO;
} Instead of YES I changed it to NO and NO to YES

Comment: Okey. Good. Happiee Codding.